# How to setState inside static function React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to setState in a static function. But I got an error which says setState is not a function:

```
export default class SearchTab extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              name: ''
            }
          }

          static callingFun = () => {
            this.setState({ name:'ali' })
          }
        }
```

Comment: You have XY problem. Why is callingFun static?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use this.setState in a static method.Because if you use static function then a static method won't be able to access 'this' inside that function. Please refer https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/02/02/static-members-in-es6.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Statics don't have instances. They are basically shared between classes and `this` won't work in it. You should make your function a `class` function instead

Comment: can you give me simple example that will help